# Reordering this recorded macro code to not use Select?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've got this code in Excel using the macro recorder, which unticks the 'Locked' property of a slicer:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("WeekEndingPick")).Select
Selection.Locked = msoFalse
```

I don't like using `Select` \ `Selection` in VBA (except when I specifically want to visibly select a range) for a number of reasons*, it seems poor practice. Usually I can just rewrite things like this easily:

```
'Macro-recorded code
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True

'Equivilant without select / selection:
Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
```

However, the following doesn't work as `Locked` is not a property of `Range`, it's a property of `Shape`:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("WeekEndingPick")).Locked = msoFalse
```

How can I work around this?

---

*If the required worksheet isn't active, it fails. If `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, it fails. If the selection changes unexpectedly, all manner of nonsense can occur - not necessary failing, but running code against the wrong location.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it almost as soon as I went back to fiddle around in Excel. It's a property of `Slicer`:

```
ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_WeekEndingPick").Slicers("WeekEndingPick").Locked = msoFalse
```

Simple!

Comment: It's not *also* a property of a Slicer - **it's** a property of a Slicer :) You could do `activesheet.shapes(slicerIndex).locked = msoFalse` too and substitute the `slicerIndex` with an index corresponding to the slicer.

Comment: Also you could make a `Dim slic as Slicer` - `Slicer` type variable and assign the reference to the correct Slicer and then take advantage of the early binding which comes with full intelli-sense etc.

Comment: @vba4all Yeah, I'd do that if I needed to do more with the slicer, but in this case it's one line vs three. Removed 'also' from the answer ;)